# How should I create a Tree structure in Rally of defects with respect to user story

Tags: treeview, rally, user-stories, defects

I am able to get tree structure for the user stories but want it same for defects also which are related to particular user story so that at a singe screen I can see both user stories and the related defects.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `features: [{ftype:'groupingsummary'}]` of ExtJS to group defects by user stories and even summarize by some other field, in the code below by PlanEstimate. To group defects by user story Requirement attribute on defect is used, which points to the related story. In this example defects are filtered by Iteration.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select Iteration:',
        labelWidth: 100
    },
    onScopeChange: function() {
        this.makeStore();
    },
    makeStore: function() {
        var filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
            property: 'Requirement',
            operator: '!=',
            value: null
        });

        filter= filter.and(this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter());
        filter.toString();

        Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                model: 'Defect',
                fetch: ['ObjectID', 'FormattedID', 'Name', 'State', 'Requirement', 'PlanEstimate'],
                autoLoad: true,
                filters: [filter],
                listeners: {
                    load: this.onDataLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
                });
    },
    onDataLoaded: function(store, records){
        if (records.length === 0) {
            this.notifyNoDefects();
        }

        else{
            if (this.notifier) {
                this.notifier.destroy();
            }
            var that = this;
            var promises = [];
            _.each(records, function(defect) {
                promises.push(this.getStory(defect, this));
            },this);

            Deft.Promise.all(promises).then({
                success: function(results) {
                    that.defects = results;
                    that.makeGrid();
                }
            });
        }

    },

    getStory: function(defect, scope) {
        var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
        var that = scope;
            var storyOid = defect.get('Requirement').ObjectID;
            Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
            scope: this,
            success: function(model, operation) {
                fetch: ['FormattedID','ScheduleState'],
                model.load(storyOid, {
                    scope: this,
                    success: function(record, operation) {
                        var storyScheduleState = record.get('ScheduleState');
                        var storyFid = record.get('FormattedID');
                        var defectRef = defect.get('_ref');
                        var defectOid  = defect.get('ObjectID');
                        var defectFid = defect.get('FormattedID');
                        var defectPlanEstimate = defect.get('PlanEstimate');
                        var defectName  = defect.get('Name');
                        var defectState = defect.get('State');
                        var story = defect.get('Requirement');

                        result = {
                                    "_ref"          : defectRef,
                                    "ObjectID"      : defectOid,
                                    "FormattedID"   : defectFid,
                                    "Name"          : defectName,
                                    "PlanEstimate"  : defectPlanEstimate,
                                    "State"         : defectState,
                                    "Requirement"   : story,
                                    "StoryState"    : storyScheduleState,
                                    "StoryID"       : storyFid  
                                };
                        deferred.resolve(result);    
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return deferred; 
    },

    makeGrid: function() {
        var that = this;
        if (this.grid) {
            this.grid.destroy();
        }

        var gridStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: that.defects,
            groupField: 'StoryID',
            pageSize: 1000,
        });

        this.grid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            itemId: 'defectGrid',
            store: gridStore,
            features: [{ftype:'groupingsummary'}],
            minHeight: 500,
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                    text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },

                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', 
                },
                {
                    text: 'State', dataIndex: 'State',
                        summaryRenderer: function() {
                            return "PlanEstimate Total"; 
                        }
                },
                {
                    text: 'PlanEstimate', dataIndex: 'PlanEstimate',
                    summaryType: 'sum'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Story', dataIndex: 'Story',
                    renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
                        return '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/userstory/' + record.get('Requirement').ObjectID + '" target="_blank">' + record.get('Requirement').FormattedID + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Story Schedule State', dataIndex: 'StoryState',
                }
            ]
        });

        this.add(this.grid);
        this.grid.reconfigure(gridStore);
    },
    notifyNoDefects: function() {
        if (this.grid) {
            this.grid.destroy();
        }
        if (this.notifier) {
            this.notifier.destroy();
        }
        this.notifier =  Ext.create('Ext.Container',{
                xtype: 'container',
                itemId: 'notifyContainer',
                html: "No Defects found matching selection."
            });
        this.add( this.notifier);  

    }
});
```

[image]